# How to display line feeds in json in C# Messagebox

Tags: c#, json

I am formatting exception data to make it readable. This is what it should look like in C# MessageBox:

```
{
 "error": "String
  2/29/2015
  does not match regex pattern"
}
```

No matter what I use for line breaks in the json it does not break the line. I have tried \n and \r\n and Environment.Newline.
I can't format it at the point of the MessageBox implementation, it must be done where the exception is handled.

Here is how I create the json:

```
var errorMessage = string.Format("{{'error': '{0}'}}", "String \n2/29/20115\n does not match regex pattern");
```

Comment: can you please try <br> and see

Comment: Did you try to use `\\n` instead of `\n`? It shall work like this.

Comment: I think you need another slash in front of your carriage return so it would be \\n vs \n.

Comment: I'm getting three lines with your code.